# Return matching enum when any matching value

Tags: java, performance, stream, java-stream

Using Java Streams, I want to return the matching enum value or throw exception. The enum values is array of objects having variant length.
For the inner filtering, using `for` loop i've achieved the desired behavior, but how can I use stream there too?

```
public enum Person {

cat1("abc"),
cat2("def", "gh1"),

private String[] dummy;

Person(String... dummy) {
        this.dummy = dummy;
}

    public static Person byVal(String val) {
        return Person.stream()
                .filter(x -> {
  here-----           for(String s1 : x.dummy) {
                        if(s1.equalsIgnoreCase(val)) {
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                    return false;
                })
                .findFirst().
                orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("illegal value"));
    }

    public static Stream<Person> stream() {
        return Stream.of(values());
    }
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be a bit cleaner:

```
enum Person{

    cat1("abc"),
    cat2("def", "gh1");

    private static final  Set<Person> ALL = EnumSet.allOf(Person.class);

    private String[] dummy;

    Person(String... dummy) {
        this.dummy = dummy;
    }

    public static Person byVal(String val) {

        return ALL
                .stream()
                .filter(x -> Arrays.stream(x.dummy).anyMatch(y -> y.equalsIgnoreCase(val)))
                .findAny()
                .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("Not found : " + val));
    }

}
```

Comment: @NoviceUser the only way for that to happen is declare a `dog(null)` for example. it's *you* who has the control of enum instances

Answer (score 1):

You can do so with:

```
Person.stream()
      .filter(x -> Arrays.stream(x.dummy)
                         .anyMatch(s -> s.equalsIgnoreCase(val)))
      .findFirst()
      .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("illegal value"));
```

Comment: every time `values` is called a kitten dies

Comment: @Eugene Why? Could you please explain?

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner `values` returns an array, which is mutable by definition, while enum instances are not, so a defensive copy is made every time via `clone`

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner no no! thank you for the news letter, you are keeping me awake late for the second night because of that :)

Comment: @Eugene : is not `values` what is better to use then?

Comment: @NoviceUser there's nothing "better" it's just that if you are doing searches for example without returning this array, you can cache them, instead of calling values all the time. this is a personal preference and this is a *very* premature optimization to begin with